# convert generic list to string list

Tags: c#, string, list, generics, casting

Is there a way to convert a generic list to list...I tried like this but I get an exception....Please help

```
Class Demo
{
    public list<string> convert()
    {
        List<example> eg = new List<example>();
        eg.Add(new example{"Hello"});
        eg.Add(new example{"World"});
        List<string> str = new List<string>();
        str = eg.Cast<string>().ToList(); //Returns an System.InvalidCastException.
                             // Is there a way to cast a generic list to string list..
        return str;
    }
}

Class example
{
     public string name{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your code has all kinds of problems. This wouldn't even compile, so you wouldn't get an exception. Please include a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. Pseudo-code is not enough.

Comment: Creating a new list in advance with `List<string> str = new List<string>();` is superfluous because `.ToList()` creates a new list and does not fill the existing list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a projection, not a cast. That's because your `example` class cannot be casted to `string`. In LINQ, projection is done by `Select` method:

```
return eg.Select(x => x.name).ToList();
```

Comment: I think that it will return only the "name" in the list... What if I want my complete model??

Answer (score 1):

Any `List<T>` is a generic list; what you want to do is extract a property from a list of objects, not perform a cast. That can be done using LINQ:

```
str = eg.Select(x => x.name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Or the good old way (.NET 2.0):

```
foreach (var example in eg)
{
   str.Add(example.name);
}
```